# Another sufficient condition for two matrices having a common eigenvector ?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A , B$ be complex $n \times n$ matrices such
that $AB = BA^2$, and assume $A$ has no eigenvalue of absolute value $1$ , then is it true that $A$ and $B$ have a common (nonzero) eigenvector ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $v$ an eigenvector. It follows that
$$ABv=\lambda^2 Bv.$$
Repeating this argument, 
$$A(B^nv)=\lambda^{2^n}(B^nv).$$
It follows that $\lambda^{2^n}$ are all eigenvalues of $A$. Thus, $\lambda^{2^k}=\lambda^{2^l}$ for some $k<l$.

If $\lambda=0$, then $Bv$ is also an eigenvector of $\lambda=0$. If $V$ is the subspace of eigenvectors of $0$ of $A$, then $B$ can be viewed as a linear operation on $V$. It implies that $B$ has an eigenvector in $V$. Thus $A$ and $B$ has a common eigenvector.

If $\lambda\neq0$, then $\lambda^{2^{l}-2^k}=1$ contradicting $|\lambda|\ne1$.

Comment: I don't understand , $Bv$ is also an eigenvector of $\lambda =0$ .... from this how does it follow that $A,B$ have a common eigenvector ?

Comment: If $\lambda=0$, then $A(Bv)=0$. It shows that $B$ sends a vector in $V$ to $V$. Then it's standard result saying that $B$ must have an eigenvector in $V$. I'm not sure how to explain better :-)

Comment: @QuangHoang How do you know that $Bv\ne0$ in order to conclude that $\lambda^2$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$?

Comment: @user26857 thanks for pointing that out. At any point that $B^kv=0$, then $B^{k-1}v$ is the common eigenvector of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @QuangHoang Of course! My point was that this should be inserted into the proof.