# Given complex matrices $X, Y$ where $XY=YX^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given complex matrices $X, Y$ where $XY=YX^2$. Below are $3$ questions.

1. If $Yv$ is an eigenvector of $X$ corresponding to eigenvalue $k$, is $k$ > $0$?
2. Assume $X$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ where $\lambda>1$, is $0$ an eigenvalue of $Y$?
3. If the nullity of $Y$ is 1. Assume $X$ is a $n\times n$ matrix now and it has $n$ real eigenvalues and they are $\geq 2$. What can you find about the set of eigenvalues of $X$?

For question 1, $XYYv=YX^2Yv\Rightarrow XY^2v=K^2Y^2v$, so I conclude $k^2$ is also an eigenvalue of $X$, by this meaning, $k=s^2$, then is it possible to conclude $k\geq 0$?

For question 2,3, from [Showing Two Operators Share an Eigenvector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389678/showing-two-operators-share-an-eigenvector), I can find $X$ and $Y$ have a common eigenvector.... Showing $0$ is an eigenvalue, that is we can show if $Y$ is invertible.

Can someone give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: Are your matrices complex or real?

Comment: They are complex

Comment: How do you conclude for 1.? We have $XYv = kYv$ i.e $YX^2v = kYv$

Comment: 1 may be not correct, just guess. But I think $k$ is square of something or it has some other properties..

Comment: I'm confused about 3. Do we assume $X$ has at least two real eigenvalues or that all of them are real and $\geqslant 2$?! What is one to conclude about the eigenvalues of $X$? Any specific conjecture in mind?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have modified it. I think it is similar to the second one, just a set with {$2^{2^n}|\text{some conditions on n}$}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer for now.

1. is false. Take $X = \left [ \begin{array}{cc}1 & i \\ 0 & 0\end{array} \right ]$. We have $X=X^2$, but $0$ is also an eigenvalue ($X$ is singular).

One might ask if the eigenvalues have to be real in the first place. For idempotent matrices, it is true - either $0$ or $1$. I'm not sure about the more general $XY=YX^2$ case.

2. is true. Let $Xu = \lambda u$ for some $\lambda >1$ and $u\neq 0$. Suppose $Y$ is invertible, which implies $Y^nu\neq 0$ for every $n$. The equalities
   $$ XYu = YX^2u = \lambda ^2Yu $$
   imply $\lambda ^2$ is also an eigenvalue of $X$. We can repeat this, so if $XY^nu = \lambda ^{2^n}Y^nu$, then
   $$ XY^{n+1}u = XYY^nu = YXXY^nu = \lambda ^{2^n}YXY^nu = \lambda ^{2^{n+1}}Y^{n+1}u $$
   so all $\lambda ^{2^{n}}$ are eigenvalues of $X$. But that's impossible, since $\lambda >1$. So we have to give up invertibility of $Y$. Equivalently, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $Y$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apparently, 3 is based on 2, with the nullity 1 of $Y$, then the only one eigenvector of $Y$ corresponding to 0 is the common eigenvector corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue of $X$. Hence the set of eigenvalues of $X$ is {$2^{2^m}|m=0,1,2,\cdots ,n-1$}.      Is this correct?